# How to insert data in bulk by using the feature of firstOrCreate efficiently in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to insert multiple data in laravel. For just inserting, i would have use just `insert($arr)` method, however, i don't want to insert duplicate data. So, i am using `firstOrCreate` eloquent methods. And, my code looks like:

```
        $unit_lists = json_decode($request->unit_lists);

        foreach($unit_lists as $uk => $uv){
            $uav = UnitAmenityValue::firstOrcreate(
                [
                    'amenity_value_id' => $request->amenityValueSelect,
                    'unit_id' => $uv
                ],
                [
                    'uav_status' => '1'
                ]
            );
        }
```

Currently, this does the work. However, i don't know either it is the efficient way to do it. As unit lists could have `30-50` or even more data in array. And, running 50+ query to insert data does not seem good to me. So, is there any other  efficient way to achieve the intended results.

All I want is to insert data to the table, by checking if there is already a row with given `amenity_value_id` and `unit_id`. If there is already a row, then no need to do anything, and if there is not any row yet insert new row with provided `amenity_value_id`, `unit_id` and `uav_status = 1`

Comment: your query is fine so whats error you getting?

Comment: @VikasKatariya I am looking for some efficient way, with this method it gonna run the insert query for 50 times if there are 50 unit ids in the list. So, is there any more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: @AayushDahal did it work to u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using InsertOrIgnore:

If you are using Laravel 5.8 +

First you need to add unique key combine `amenity_value_id` and `unit_id`

```php
$table->unique(['amenity_value_id', 'unit_id']);
```

And just use [InsertOrIgnore](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts), so when the `amenity_value_id` and `unit_id` are duplicated in db, the error will not be thrown, and just ingore:

```php
foreach($unit_lists as $uk => $uv){
    $datas []= [
        'amenity_value_id' => $request->amenityValueSelect,
        'unit_id' => $uv,
        'uav_status' => 1
    ];
}

UnitAmenityValue::insertOrIgnore($datas);
```

If you are using Laravel below 5.8, you can do it like this:

```php
foreach($unit_lists as $uk => $uv){
    $datas []= [
        'amenity_value_id' => $request->amenityValueSelect,
        'unit_id' => $uv,
        'uav_status' => 1
    ];
}

$value_string = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($datas), '(' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($datas[0]), '?')) . ')')); 
$values = [];

// Flattens the array
foreach($datas as $row) {
    foreach($row as $value) {
        $values[] = $value;
    }
}
\DB::insert("INSERT IGNORE INTO (amenity_value_id, unit_id, uav_status) VALUES {$value_string}", $values);
```

---

Another trick:

## Find the diff and insert once:

1. select the `amenity_value_id, unit_id` which in the table and in the request, then put them in `$exists_datas` (remember to add index on `amenity_value_id` and `unit_id`, so the query will be faster)
2. get the different datas in `$exists_datas` and request `$datas`;
3. insert the different datas at once.

```php
$unit_lists = json_decode($request->unit_lists);

$datas = array();
// Get the datas from request:
foreach($unit_lists as $uk => $uv){
    $datas []= [
        'amenity_value_id' => $request->amenityValueSelect,
        'unit_id' => $uv
    ];
}

// Make the db where params:
$params = array_map(function ($item) {
    $amenity_value_id = $item['amenity_value_id'];
    $unit_id = $item['unit_id'];
    return DB::raw("($amenity_value_id, $unit_id)");
}, $datas);

// find out the exists params in db
$exists_datas = UnitAmenityValue::whereIn(DB::raw('(amenity_value_id, unit_id)'), $params)
                                ->select('amenity_value_id', 'unit_id')
                                ->get()
                                ->toArray();
// Get the diff datas which will be inserted
$inserted_datas = array_diff($exists_datas, $datas);
$inserted_datas = collect($inserted_datas)->map(function($item) { 
                          $item['uav_status'] = 1; 
                          return $item; })->all();

UnitAmenityValue::insert($inserted_datas);
```